# How to update timer interval in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer

I am working on a game where the rate of change of an image changes over time. At first the image change every two seconds and then it will speed up.

```
var change = 2.0

func setupGame(){
    change = 2.0

    changeImage()
}

func changeImage(){
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(change, target: self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.changeColors), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    change -= 0.1
}
```

The problem is that it speeds up too much and it doesn't stop. Eventually the change value becomes negative.

Any way to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are forgetting two things.

- First, you are creating a new repeating timer every time the timer fires. You need to `invalidate` the old timer before creating the new timer. And since you are going to replace the timer anyway, you do *not* want this to be a repeating timer; you need to say `false` instead of `true`.
- Second, if you don't want `change` to keep getting smaller, you need some sort of condition where you check how small `change` has become and, if you don't want to get any faster, don't decrement it.